# Disk I/O utilization up to 100% after tuning InnoDB-related MySQL configuration

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb

I have added following lines to "my.conf":

```
query_cache_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

After that Disk utilization started raising, reached 100% and holds steady, also CPU is up a bit because of Disk I/O related tasks, but physical memory is just 50% used.

I am bit lost what is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, the [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) is supposed to be 25% of [**innodb_buffer_pool_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size). In your case, you should add that variable as follows:

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
innodb_log_file_size=128M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

Click Here to Learn to Resize innodb_log_file_size -> https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1265/877

Here is a way you can setup the correct size of innodb_buffer_pool_size based on the amount of InnoDB Data you currently have. Run this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(KBS/POWER(1024, 
IF(PowerOf1024<0,0,IF(PowerOf1024>3,0,PowerOf1024)))+0.49999), 
SUBSTR(' KMG',IF(PowerOf1024<0,0, 
IF(PowerOf1024>3,0,PowerOf1024))+1,1)) recommended_innodb_buffer_pool_size 
FROM (SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) KBS FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE engine='InnoDB') A, 
(SELECT 2 PowerOf1024) B;
```

If `recommended_innodb_buffer_pool_size` comes back more than 75% of installed RAM, then use 75% of installed RAM as the recommended value. As mentioned before, set the innodb_log_file_size accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [innodb_flush_method documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method) use of O_DIRECT can have either a 
positive or negative effect on your performance

Quote from the documentation:

> Depending on hardware configuration, setting innodb_flush_method to
>   O_DIRECT can either have either a positive or negative effect on
>   performance. Benchmark your particular configuration to decide which
>   setting to use.

Comment: this is a bit of topic, but I don't want to restart MySQL server right now, and site seems to work so far, how risky is it to leave server running all day with 100% disk utilization? Or should I act immediately in this case?

Comment: If you have the possibility to reproduce it on a test-environment, you can experiment with other values for the innodb_flush_method.

Comment: Did you check out http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl ? It will also give you a few hints on performance tuning.